# outlook - customize calendar areas

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have 2 calendars in my outlook, my weekly view (which shows days on top, and hours on the bottom portion), and a second calendar showing who is not working today.

The second calendar also shows the hours, but it's not relevant in this case so I'd like to hide that area, the top part (weekday view), has longer lists so I always need to scroll down, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Currently it looks like this:

```
[1][3]
[2][4]
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
[1]|3|
[2]|3|
```

with #3 going all the way down so it uses 100% of the height.

Here is an actual screenshot, if it helps:
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such way to change this. This is by design.

Comment: NOoooooooooooo!

Answer (score 0):

Work this around: View second calendar in a new Window.

Menu **View** > **Open in New Window** clones Outlook window so you have freedom to set up your second view as you wish.

I know this needs re-creation after each restart of the Outlook, but if you restart it once per 2 weeks (as I do) it is bearable.

Some boosters: You can also add the above menu command to the Quick Access Toolbar on the top so you can clone main window with a single click (see the following image). Theroetically, an autoexec VBA macro can set up everything for you when you start the Outlook.

[image]